# Simple Numpy Min and Max from certain column

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, max, min

I have input file that has about 8 columns and all i have to do it find min and max value for every column. I don't mind finding it column by column. Looking for a quick suggestion. Thanks

Input file

```
00022da391f0 00022dcea331   9    19152.00    2128.00    1330.0    8404.0    424.0  
00022da391f0 00022d127ece   84    349124.00    4156.24    1773.5    33616.0    333.0  
0004232b94d0 00022db0b1b7   55    35204.00    640.07    482.0    1688.0    341.0  
00022db0b1b7 00055d102f8c   10    17371.00    1737.10    676.5    8619.0    333.0  
00022db0b1b7 00022d127ece   53    510239.00    9627.15    1531.0    130610.0    368.0
```

Code

```
infile = open('input', 'r')
file_lines = file.readlines(infile)

for line in file_lines[:,2]:
    items = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    max_item = max(items)
    min_item = min(items)
print max_item
```

The output is supposed to be the max value in col[2] i.e. the column 3 from input file. But instead i get the error

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "min_max.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in file_lines[:,2]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: You can't use `numpy`-style indexing on vanilla Python lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`file.readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) does not return a numpy array, but a list of lines(strings). You need to use something like [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.loadtxt('input', usecols=[2]).max()
84.0
>>> np.loadtxt('input', usecols=[2], dtype=int).max()
84
```

If you want to do it with `open`, you need to iterate lines, split lines, get the 3rd items (`[2]`), ....

BTW, you don't need to use `file.readlines` because you don't need all lines at once. Itearing file will yield lines.